# Merge request: [word-selection] into [word-choice]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

The tag [word-selection](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-selection) on the main site has only 6 questions tagged with it and it seems to me that it has the same meaning as the tag [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice). I propose to merge them.

Comment: Sounds great. go for it!